# Toast not displaying when C function is called

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface, toast

I have a service that can either be started with a launcher or runs on boot. The problem is that when I call a C function with JNI, all the `Toast` notifications are no longer displayed, whereas if I call only the java method, the `Toast` notifications display just fine. What causes this and how can I fix it?

**Note:** 
If the C function does something simple like calls back to java and terminates, the `Toast` notifications will display. My function however, has an infinite loop used to handle interrupts.

**ServiceLauncher**

```
public class ServiceLauncher extends AppCompatActivity  {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

**MyService**

```
public class MyService extends Service  {
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Terminated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags, int startid)  {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        javaMethod(); /*toast displays if this is called*/
        cMethodFromJNI(); /*toast does not display if this is called*/
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

**C code structure**

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_className_cMethodFromJNI(JNIEnv *env, jclass type) {


    jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, type, "javaMethod", "(I)V");

   // open and read some fd (not shown)

    for (;;) {
        // wait on change in fd and act on it (not shown)
        callJavaAgain(env,type,mid)
        }
    }
   //close fd (not shown)
    exit(0);
}
```

**EDIT:** I've changed the code like so, following the answer below. Seems like the situation is exactly the same as before, perhaps I am missing something.

**Revised C code structure**

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL

Java_className_cMethodFromJNI(JNIEnv * env, jclass type) {

    /*cache JVM*/
    int status = ( * env) - > GetJavaVM(env, & jvm);
    if (status != 0) {
        LOGD("failed to retrieve *env");
        exit(1);
    }
    attachedThread();
}

void attachedThread() {
        /* get a new environment and attach a new thread */
        JNIEnv * newEnv;
        JavaVMAttachArgs args;
        args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6; // choose your JNI version
        args.name = NULL; // if you want to give the java thread a name
        args.group = NULL; // you can assign the java thread to a ThreadGroup
        ( * jvm) - > AttachCurrentThread(jvm, & newEnv, & args);
        jclass cls = ( * newEnv) - > FindClass(newEnv, "fully/qualified/class/name");
        jmethodID mid = ( * newEnv) - > GetStaticMethodID(newEnv, cls, "callJavaAgain", "(V)V");
        // open and read some fd (not shown)

        for (;;) {
            // wait on change in fd and act on it (not shown)
            intermediaryFunction(newEnv, cls, mid);
        }
    }
        //close fd (not shown)
    exit(0);
}

void intermediaryFunction(JNIEnv * newEnv, jclass cls, jmethodID mid) {
    //do some stuff (not shown)
    ( * newEnv) - > CallStaticVoidMethod(newEnv, cls, mid);
}
```

Comment: there's not really enough information here. what is cMethodFromJNI? does anything get displayed in the logcat when the toast is called? what is javaMethod?

Comment: @kirinthos with a simple function that calls back to java the toasts will display, but with the more complex one I am using, they never do. Should I make a thread to call the C function?

Comment: no i call C code on the UI thread all the time, there's some trickiness with JNIEnv, but I don't see you reaching that odd scenario here (and if there's nothing in the logcat then the JNIEnv isn't failing, or is doing a really good job of not telling you it's failing). can you post all of your NDK related code? how you're declaring the native method, the header that's generated and your implementation of that file

Comment: @kirinthos I added the basic structure of the C code. I suspect its something about the `for(;;)` which prevents a jump back to java to continue displaying `Toast`

Comment: aha, so it's failing because you don't release the JNIEnv on the main thread because that for loop is infinite, I'm surprised this doesn't crash the app. edit: what does callJavaAgain do? does it call back to c++? you could have an infinite call stack issue too

Comment: @kirinthos: For the moment, callJavaAgain actually calls back to the java class that called the C fn (MyService) and simply displays a logcat message. Going to add more functionality once I work this out. How should I properly release the JNIEnv so I can keep making calls back from the loop?

Comment: the loop needs to be on its own thread, take care when using the JNIEnv from alternate threads. this is a tricky subject, you will need to store the JNI virtual machine reference and acquire a reference to a JNIEnv for your new thread. before you destruct that thread it must call `JNIEnv->DetachThread` or you will crash. basically don't loop forever in calls coming from Java, use the call to start something _else_ that loops indefinitely edit: if this is what you're trying to do (loop forever in c code called from Java) tell me and I'll get you some docs as an answer post

Comment: @kirinthos yep that is exactly what I'm trying to do!

Comment: okay I'm in a meeting, I'll get you some info in about an hour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay so this topic requires some careful attention. [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html) talk about JavaVM and JNIEnv and how to interface with them. What you will need to do is store a global reference to the JavaVM that's accessible from all threads in the C code. The JVM allows a thread to get access to the JNIEnv which can get you access to a class's methods and what not. The next key problem is that you need to stash a jobject 'pointer' to the android object you call back to from the C code (which you probably already know). Make sure you call JNIEnv->DetachThread *on the thread that acquired the JNIEnv reference*.

so again:

- get JavaVM reference and store it in c code
- have java call c code to store the jobject reference for your callback
- start a thread to do looping, acquire a reference to a JNIEnv on that thread to call to java
- call DetachThread before terminating thread execution

another point of trouble is accessing c++ objects from java code, there's a neat trick where you can have c++ code *create* the java objects, and assign into a `private long _cppPointer` member on the created Java class, then add this object to some collection on a java object you have already pointer to (like an activity or something)

good luck.

edit: i finally recalled [another great source](https://thebreakfastpost.com/2012/01/21/wrapping-a-c-library-with-jni-introduction/) of information about JNI work

Comment: So I know the `JNIEnv` won't necessarily be the same between threads. I'm looking to call a method, so I need `env`, `jclass` and `jmethodID` to use `GetStaticMethodID`. With JVM stored, I can get the `env` and with  `jclass` I can get the `jmethodID`. I'm not sure how to get `jclass` from the `env` though. Can the class ID and method ID change between threads? Or can I just store them right when I get to the C code and use them in the new thread from C I will attach?

Comment: Edit: Above I mean to write `CallStaticVoidMethod` and not `GetStaticMethodID`

Comment: you can look up classes by their Java package qualifier using FindClass

Comment: This would mean I can input the method name in `jclass FindClass(JNIEnv *env, const char *name);` under `*name`?

Comment: com.example.MyStaticClassName, e.g.

Comment: Is the above edit what you meant? It seems to be working as I'm getting the desired output as before, yet still no `Toast` notifications display

Comment: afaict you probably do not want to be calling exit() from c code in a Java application, though at surface glance your calls to the environment to get everything do look correct. I don't see where you call the nested function though. (fwiw too nested functions are relatively unsupported, and are not available at all afaik in c++)

Comment: Sorry, that was a copy-paste error, fn isn't nested. I know `exit()` is only called when the program fails (going to correct that in a bit), and from the log I can tell that when it's running it never hits the `exit()`

Comment: okay, yeah you would know, calling exit from c code should crash. so you have the setup correct here, but you are still calling attachedThread on the same thread. you will need to spawn a new [thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) (this link is c++, for c use pthread)